# Unable to access External HDD in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have bought a new laptop Lenevo G500 and installed Ubuntu 13.0, I have taken out my previous laptop's HDD and trying to access it by connecting to USB port, however it has detected only once and after a restart it is not detecting it any more and saying unable to mount, I have checked other answers but none worked for me.

Can any one help please, I am getting the following error.

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc3 at /media/rinky/Dharam New: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdc3" "/media/rinky/Dharam New"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 7197  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x800006009443600) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc3': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Comment: did you try `chkdsk` on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use -t ntfs with mount.  It is old, and I believe deprecated in favor of fuse ntfs 3rd gen.  Fuse should installed.  Try replacing ntfs with ntfs-3g, and see if that helps.

There were some other options that went along with fuse like mount as user (instead of root, if mounting readwrite) and so on.  I'd try mount -o ro (Read Only) until you are sure your drive's not in an unstable state.

Good luck!